# EnityFramework DatabaseFirst Not perserving Data

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, entity-framework-5, ef-database-first

i following the `DatabaseFirst` with `EnityFramewok`, when i call the `SaveChanges` method , the data is not getting inserted in the database.

i have the checked it with `profiler` that its hitting the right database. but not saving any changes.profiler shows query which is perfect, if manfully executed, that got inserted.

[image]

```
RPC:Completed   exec sp_executesql N'insert [dbo].[UserMaster]([UserId], [Emailid], [Password], [LoginTypeid], [LastModifiedDate])
values (@0, @1, @2, @3, null)
',N'@0 int,@1 nvarchar(max) ,@2 nvarchar(max) ,@3 int',@0=8,@1=N'some@thing.com',@2=N'TN7Z-EPVOZ',@3=1  EntityFramework     sa  0   8   0   0   4220    58  2013-07-12 12:48:09.843 2013-07-12 12:48:09.843     MMDStage
```

ConnectionString:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="MMDStageEntities" connectionString="metadata=res://*/MMDModel.csdl|res://*/MMDModel.ssdl|res://*/MMDModel.msl;provider=System.Data.SqlClient;provider connection string=&quot;data source=SERVER-2;initial catalog=MMDStage;user id=**;password=******;MultipleActiveResultSets=True;App=EntityFramework&quot;" providerName="System.Data.EntityClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
  <entityFramework>
    <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.LocalDbConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
      <parameters>
        <parameter value="v11.0" />
      </parameters>
    </defaultConnectionFactory>
  </entityFramework>
</configuration>
```

Any Suggestions.

Comment: Are you using a TransactionScope? If so, don't forget to Complete() it after SaveChanges().

Comment: @Erwin you got the bullseye. i have found out this earlier.